# When is gradient flow an isometry?

Tags: geometry, analysis

$M$ is a Riemannian manifold,$f$ is a function on $M$. Under what conditions is the gradient flow $F(t)$ of $f$ an isometry for $t>0$?

Answer (score 6):

This occurs if and only if the [Hessian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Generalizations_to_Riemannian_manifolds) of the function is equal to zero.  This follows from the following facts:

1. A vector field $X$ corresponds to an isometric flow if and only if the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_X(g)$ of the metric with respect to $X$ is zero.  (See [Killing vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field).)
2. If $f$ is any function then the Hessian of $f$ is given by the formula
   $$
   \mathrm{Hess}(f) \;=\; \frac{1}{2}\mathcal{L}_{\nabla f}(g),
   $$
   where $\nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$ and $g$ is the metric.  (See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=9cekXdo52hEC&pg=PA23).)